# I keep receiving WARNING: Could not find virtual environment directory /home/site/wwwroot/antenv when I deploy my web app from Github to Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I keep receiving this error: WARNING: Could not find virtual environment directory /home/site/wwwroot/antenv

When I try to deploy my web app from GitHub to Azure Linux Web App Service.

I have even went to configuration -> Application settings and there I set SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT to true.  When I saw that it could not find the antenv virtual environment directory, in the yaml file I even changed 'venv' to 'antenv' in the following lines: python -m venv antenv, source antenv/bin/activate to solve it. However the same error persists. Please help. For reference, this is my workflow .yaml file:

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - mdapp3

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.11'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv antenv
          source antenv/bin/activate
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
        
      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)
      
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            . 
            !venv/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: .
          
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'mdapp3'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_5CXXXXXX }}
```

I shall also share my application logs for reference:

```cs
Container mdapp3_0_e7cbb7be couldn't be started: Logs = 2023-09-18T15:51:45.405744940Z    _____                               
2023-09-18T15:51:45.405781443Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____  
2023-09-18T15:51:45.405787144Z  /  /_\  \\___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \ 
2023-09-18T15:51:45.405791744Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/ 
2023-09-18T15:51:45.405796145Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2023-09-18T15:51:45.405800545Z         \/      \/                  \/ 
2023-09-18T15:51:45.405805046Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2023-09-18T15:51:45.405809046Z 
2023-09-18T15:51:45.405813047Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2023-09-18T15:51:45.405817147Z Python 3.11.4
2023-09-18T15:51:45.405821147Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2023-09-18T15:51:48.717385073Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2023-09-18T15:51:48.866272740Z App Command Line not configured, will attempt auto-detect
2023-09-18T15:51:49.236537117Z Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.
2023-09-18T15:51:49.266362015Z Launching oryx with: create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -virtualEnvName antenv -defaultApp /opt/defaultsite
2023-09-18T15:51:49.325928903Z Could not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2023-09-18T15:51:49.325963607Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2023-09-18T15:51:49.327749380Z Build Operation ID: 5f2419ea-178e-4da1-a73d-cb0a8cd3e22c
2023-09-18T15:51:49.538150824Z Oryx Version: 0.2.20230707.1, Commit: 0bd28e69919b5e8beba451e8677e3345f0be8361, ReleaseTagName: 20230707.1
2023-09-18T15:51:49.550486823Z Detected an app based on Flask
2023-09-18T15:51:49.551541125Z Generating `gunicorn` command for 'app:app'
2023-09-18T15:51:49.586169290Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2023-09-18T15:51:49.634218359Z WARNING: Could not find virtual environment directory /home/site/wwwroot/antenv.
2023-09-18T15:51:49.634248962Z WARNING: Could not find package directory /home/site/wwwroot/__oryx_packages__.
2023-09-18T15:51:50.673759167Z [2023-09-18 15:51:50 +0000] [72] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2023-09-18T15:51:50.734923310Z [2023-09-18 15:51:50 +0000] [72] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (72)
2023-09-18T15:51:50.757802233Z [2023-09-18 15:51:50 +0000] [72] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2023-09-18T15:51:50.757829636Z [2023-09-18 15:51:50 +0000] [75] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 75
2023-09-18T15:51:51.464761425Z [2023-09-18 15:51:51 +0000] [75] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2023-09-18T15:51:51.464798029Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-09-18T15:51:51.464804929Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2023-09-18T15:51:51.464810430Z     worker.init_process()
2023-09-18T15:51:51.464815630Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2023-09-18T15:51:51.464830932Z     self.load_wsgi()
2023-09-18T15:51:51.464835832Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2023-09-18T15:51:51.464841033Z     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2023-09-18T15:51:51.464845833Z                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-09-18T15:51:51.464850734Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2023-09-18T15:51:51.464855734Z     self.callable = self.load()
2023-09-18T15:51:51.464860535Z                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-09-18T15:51:51.464865235Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2023-09-18T15:51:51.464870236Z     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2023-09-18T15:51:51.464874936Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-09-18T15:51:51.464879737Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2023-09-18T15:51:51.464884737Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2023-09-18T15:51:51.464889538Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-09-18T15:51:51.464894438Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2023-09-18T15:51:51.464899438Z     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
202
```

=======[LONG LOG TRUNCATED BY DETECTOR]======

I have even went to configuration -> Application settings and there I set SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT to true. When I saw that it could not find the antenv virtual environment directory, in the yaml file I even changed 'venv' to 'antenv' in the following lines: python -m venv antenv, source antenv/bin/activate to solve it. However the same error persists. Please help.

Comment: Please provide your GitHub repository link if you don't have any sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow below steps to deploy your python web application to Azure App Service:**

- Create Python Linux Azure App Service.
- Configure deployment while creating web app.
  `Deployment=> click on Enable=> Select your organization and GitHub project repository` and *branch* as *main*.

[image]

Click on `Review+Create`.

- Once the web app gets created, workflow to deploy the Python app to Azure gets created automatically in GitHub project repository(.github/workflows).
- Deployment status can be tracked in `GitHub=>Actions`.

---

***I have deployed a simple Python web app to Azure App Service using GitHub Actions.***

**Project Structure:**

[image]

**My GitHub workflow to deploy a simple python web app to Azure:**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - <web_app_name>

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.11'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
        
      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)
      
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            . 
            !venv/

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: .
          
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: '<web_app_name>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_XXXXXX }}
```

**Deployment Status:**

[image]

Once deployment completes, navigate to `Azure App Service=>Advanced Tools=>Go=> KUDU site will be opened`. Select SSH. Type `dir` and enter. Check the deployed project files.

[image]